# Design and Framework for Automating around 2000 test cases in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have around more than 2000 test cases that needs to be automated.What is the process and key factors i need to follow while creating framework? (For Instance code reuse,Use Page Object Model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You should keep in you mind all key points and features of the automation framework:-

re-usability of the code.
screenshot of all and every failure.
error log should be easy to understand.

To analyse the test case: you can keep multiple test cases in excel sheet so that you can easily analyze the test results
```

Answer (score 0):

From the test case side :
you can keep multiple test cases in excel sheet so that you can easily analyze the test results .

Page object model is good when you have less no pages and controls on each page .

its always better to write methods which can be re-used .

Keyword driven framework will be good approach for this.